# QtCreator Python.h with Anaconda Python

Tags: python, c++, qt, python-2.7

Trying to embed anaconda Python into a Qt application.  As a first step, I just want to get Python.h including properly.

I am running Qt4, Python 2.7.9, and OS X 10.9.

The project.pro has:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /home/myuser/anaconda/include/python2.7 /home/myuser/anaconda/include

LIBS += -L/home/myuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7 -lpython2.7
```

appended to the end.

In spite of this, I am getting the system installed python 2.7.5.  This is verified by running `import sys`, `sys.version` and `sys.path`.

Clearly, I am missing something - a compiler flag?  New to QtCreator, so any insight appreciated.

Comment: in a terminal type `which python`.  And then you can also put `python --version`.  If it isn't the one you want, then it is sitting in your `PATH` variable.  Often times the path variable gets edited in `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`.  Open both of those files and check to see if you `PATH` variable is getting appended or prepended there.  There may also be other environmental variables that python uses that have been set for your system.

Comment: @phyatt all environment variables are properly set.  Anaconda is normal working Python, so no issues in having it run via `python`.  I wonder if the `qmake` being used by QTCreator is not using some other environment variables?  The command line qmake is one that I have installed via homebrew.  Presumably this is the `qmake` QTCreator is also using?