# Use Anaconda's Python in my Qt C++ application

Tags: python, c++, qt, anaconda

I intent to use Anaconda's Python in my Qt C++ application to call some scikit-learn algorithms from within my C++ code. For some reason I cannot figure out how to do the integration. I wonder if anybody knows a step by step procedure to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your C++ code works with Qt <= 5.9.7. (or more precisely [Anaconda's current Qt version)](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/qt) you can include Python (in this case 3.6) by adding

```
INCLUDEPATH += /home/[username]/anaconda3/include/python3.6m

LIBS += -L/home/[username]/anaconda3/lib/ -lpython3.6m
```

to your .pro file.

If you need a Qt version which is higher than the one provided by Anaconda, have a look at [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48398899/include-anaconda-python-3-6-in-qt-c-application-without-anacondas-qt-version/51254036#51254036). Now you should be able to include the `Python.h` header in your application.

*Remark*: Keep in mind that Python provides its own signals and slots mechanism which can apparently clash with Qt's. That's why I added

```
CONFIG += no_keywords
```

to my pro file, and replaced all signals and slots occurrences like described [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this would work for you, but I'd look at [this article](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq23-pythonqt.html). It provides at least a way to start a python interpreter from within the Qt application.

I think this might work, depending on the complexity of the thing.

You can find more on the [PythonQt](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/).

I don't know how well it will work with external packages though.

Otherwise, you could use [PySide2](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python), which allows you to create GUIs using Qt5 framework in python.

I hope it helps.